# In Microsoft Dynamics 365, how does one correctly and successfully add a menu item button to a table?

Tags: controller, menuitem, dynamics-365-operations, sysoperationframework

I'm currently working my way through "[Creating dialogs using the SysOperation framework](https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/dynamics-365-for/9781786468864/083dc41f-d5fe-4cdc-bb97-22f89ab32254.xhtml)" in Dynamics 365 for Finance and Operations Development Cookbook - Fourth Edition.

While the authors are generally good at providing step-by-step information, sometimes they make assumptions about our knowledge, experience, the environment we are working in, etc. which are not entirely correct.

I've just created `class CustBalanceUIBuilder extends SysOperationAutomaticUIBuilder` and added a new action menu item called `CustBalanceController`.

Next, they cryptically tell us to "Place the menu item at Accounts receivable | Customers | All Customers | Customer | Balance | Display balance, as shown in the following screenshot", without actually telling us how to do such a thing.

I've figured out that I don't currently have any extension "CustTable.Extension1", but that I can create an extension by browsing the AOT, finding "CustTable" under "Form" and then clicking "Create extension.

I was then able to browse the design dialog and insert a menu item button with the name "CustBalanceController", as displayed.

By setting the "Text" property to "Display Balance", I can see the button on the menu, but the preview does not display either the account list nor the form.  Also, there is some strange tool-tip artifact that rapidly rotates through countless seemingly random phrases whenever I try to interact with the preview.

If I try viewing in my local instance of D365, the menu item is missing.  I've confirmed that I *do* have the role which is associated with the duty which is associated with the privilege which is associated with the menu item.

Comment: So far, I have not been able to reproduce the issue you describe in the last paragraph. For me, the menu item appears in the UI and the behavior is as described in the cookbook. You can take a look at my implementation at https://github.com/FH-Inway/D365FOCookbook, maybe you can find a difference to your implementation. It could also depend on the exact version of D365FO you are on, which is generally a good idea to include as information in your questions.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the strange tool-tip issue. Not sure what the cause is there, but you will find that with some experience, the form preview is not something you will really need or use.

Comment: Finally some meta remarks: (1) I see your questions usually use the dynamics-finops tag. I recommend you use the dynamics-365-operations tag instead, because it is the "older" tag and has more eyes on it. IMHO, dynamics-finops should be a synonym. The tags x++ and axapta are also good choices to get more eyes on your questions.

Comment: (2) While the cookbook is a good resource, I wouldn't recommend it as a learning resource.  In this particular case, check the [Add a form extension to a project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/extend-elements-finance-operations/3-form) unit from Microsoft Learn and the following lab which provides you with a VM configured for the exercise.

Comment: @FH-Inway, cheers for all the comments.  I'll try to find time to check into this tomorrow.  :-)